# PHP return object instance from __getStatic()

Tags: php, singleton, static-members

PHP has a *magic* method `__getStatic()` that allows overloading of static method calls. I have a class with a fluent interface which performs integrity checks. I call it like this:-

```
$check = new CheckSomeCondition();
$check->forActive()->sites(array(1,2,3))->check();
```

However, I would like to call it like this:-

```
CheckSomeCondition::forActive()->sites(array(1,2,3))->check();
```

I thought that having this magic method in my base class would allow me to do this:-

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = new self();
    return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $args);
}
```

But `new self()` produces an instance of the class that the calling code is in, and not the class which `__callStatic()` exists in, why is this? and how can I get around it?

I have also tried `new static` and this does the same thing.

I know this must be possible because Laravel's QueryBuilder has an interface like `DB::table()->...` and this uses method chaining, returning object instances, not static classes. I have had a look at the Laravel code, but I think they create the instances somewhere else in the application and they are stored in a class member ready to be returned.

Comment: "and this uses method chaining which can't be done with static methods" --- it just return an object. "method chaining" is not a magic, it's just invoking an object's method. Anyway, your idea is terrible - don't do that

Comment: @zerkms Method chaining is returning the current instance of an object in a method so that another method can be called directly. This cannot be done with static methods because in PHP you cannot return `self` - the static class

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php You can, but it's a terrible idea

Comment: @zerkms Why is it terrible?

Comment: @Petah: because static is more complicated to deal with. Static by itself should be avoided as much as you can (*always*)

Answer (score 2):

The magic method `__callStatic` is only called for methods *which don't exist*, so in this case it will simply not run.

Consider the following simplified example:

```
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        echo "Running instance method bar()";
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        echo "__callStatic called for non-existent method $method";
    }
}

Foo::bar();
```

If you run this ([here's an online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yYkoT0)) you will see that it is the "real" `bar()` method that is called.

There can only be one method named `bar` on the class, so PHP's only other option would be to complain that `bar()` should be `static` - which it does, but non-fatally.

---

The reason you see an instance of the calling class is not that `$instance` is instantiated with the wrong class, but because when your method is called non-statically, `$this` "leaks" from the enclosing scope.

In the following example, `$this` ends up being the instance of `Bar`:

```
class Foo
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        echo get_class($this);
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public function doSomethingElse()
    {
        Foo::doSomething();
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->doSomethingElse();
```

[Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PK18Cw)

Comment: Right! that makes sense. So do you think my only option is to have a static method `get_instance()` which returns an instance, and then do `TheClass::get_instance()->method()...`

Comment: I have looked at the laravel code, but I think they create the instances somewhere else in the application and they are stored in a class member

Comment: @rgvcorley Your `get_instance()` idea is what is known as the "Factory Pattern", and is certainly a respectable approach.

Comment: figured it out - just need to use both `__call()` and `__callStatic` and prefix all my method names so that non of the method names I call exist. Then all calls go through either `__call()` or `__callStatic()`.

Answer (score 1):

As @IMSoP pointed out, `__getStatic()` is only called if there is **no method** with the name called - not just if there isn't a static method with the name.

So the workaround to allow calls such as `CheckClass::forActive->sites()` is to give all the non static method names a prefix such as '_' and have a magic method `__call()` which will add the prefix in.

This means if I do `CheckClass::forActive()` the method `forActive()` doesn't exist, so `__getStatic()` will be called and will create an instance of the object and try to call the desired method. But the method doesn't exist because we've prefix it, so PHP will call the `__call()` magic method which will add the prefix and call the prefixed method.

So the 2 functions are:-

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = new self;
    return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $args);
}

public static function __call($method, $args)
{
    $method = 'prefix_' . $method;
    return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $args);
}

// Then all our method names need to be prefixed, like so:-
public static function prefix_SomeMethod($method, $args)
{
    // Do something
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Beware that this only really makes sense if *any* method can be used to "start" the chain - i.e. there is no fundamental context needed from the factory/constructor.

Comment: That's a good point - in my case any of the public methods can start the chain so it's fine. Thanks so much for your help!